# How to do 301 redirections after Wordpress Permalinks change

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, woocommerce

I changed the Woocommerce permalink structure of my site and I would need some 301 redirections Help.

Woocommerce product permalinks were configured according to the structure:

```
/shop/%product_cat%/
```

And now according to the structure:

```
/shop/
```

What lines do I need to add to the `.htaccess` file to do 301 redirections, please?

**UPDATE:** `/shop/%product_cat%/` is a Permalink Structure in WordPress that means `example.com/shop/category1/subcategory1/MyProduct` and `/shop/` means `example.com/shop/MyProduct` and this latter is better for SEO.

Comment: Could add your current code?

Comment: "And now according to the structure: `/shop/`" - that doesn't look like much of a "structure"?! How do you identify the product at the new URL? What does `%product_cat%` consist of?

Comment: @MrWhite

/shop/%product_cat%/ is a Permalink Structure in WordPress an means mydomain.com/shop/category1/subcategory1/MyProduct

and /shop/ means mydomain.com/shop/MyProduct 
and this latter is better for SEO

Comment: @Rojo
I did not add any code to my htaccess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `/shop/%product_cat%/` is a Permalink Structure in WordPress an means
> `example.com/shop/category1/subcategory1/MyProduct` and `/shop/` means
> `example.com/shop/MyProduct`

If the old URLs always contained two additional path segments of the form `/category1/subcategory1` followed by a single path segment containing `MyProduct` (*product-name*) then you would need to do something like the following at the *top* of your `.htaccess` file *before* the WordPress front-controller:

```
RewriteRule ^shop/[^/]+/[^/]+/([^/]+)$ /shop/$1 [R=302,L]
```

It is always better to be more specific with the regex in order to avoid conflicts.

However, if you need a more general solution that would match single *category* path segments or more than two then use something like the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^shop/(?:[^/]+/)+([^/]+)$ /shop/$1 [R=302,L]
```

The above would match any of the following URL formats and redirect them all to `/shop/MyProduct`:

- `/shop/category1/MyProduct`
- `/shop/category1/subcategory1/MyProduct`
- `/shop/category1/subcategory1/subsubcategory1/MyProduct`
- `/shop/category1/subcategory1/subsubcategory1/etc/MyProduct`

Test with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid caching issues and *only* change to a 301 (permanent) redirect (if that is the intention) when you have confirmed it works OK.

---

> **UPDATE:** myproduct page: `https://www.example.com/shop/crazy-cat-test-t-shirt/` - my old
> product page (404 error):
> `https://www.example.com/shop/women/t-shirt/crazy-cat-test-t-shirt/` -
> test adress with one category (Works):
> `https://www.example.com/shop/category/crazy-cat-test-t-shirt/`

This highlights "the problem" (as mentioned briefly in a preceding comment).... All these URLs (old *and* new) contain a trailing slash. None of your previous "example" URLs contained a trailing slash?! The `RewriteRule` directive above will not work if the requested URL contains a trailing slash because it is designed to work with the examples you posted (without a trailing slash). URLs with and without a trailing slash are two completely different URLs.

If it's currently "working" with single-category URLs then "something else" must be doing that or changing the request so the above directive matches. However, the above directive would omit the trailing slash from the (new) target, so "something else" would have needed to append the trailing slash, if that is a requirement. (?!)

If the trailing slash is *always* present on the "old" URL *and* a trailing slash is required on the "new" URL then change the above directive to read:

```
RewriteRule ^shop/(?:[^/]+/)+([^/]+/)$ /shop/$1 [R=302,L]
```

In the above, the *mandatory* trailing slash is included as part of the captured subgroup and therefore present in the `$1` backreference.

However, if the trailing slash is *optional* on the "old" URL but should always be present on the "new" URL then change the directive to read:

```
RewriteRule ^shop/(?:[^/]+/)+([^/]+)/?$ /shop/$1/ [R=302,L]
```

In the above, the *optional* trailing slash is outside the captured group, so we must manually include this on the target URL, where it is mandatory.

Comment: Thank you.  I have tried both codes but none work.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by it "doesn't work"? Do you get an error? Incorrect redirect? _Nothing_? The above would certainly redirect the URLs as stated, if indeed they are processed. I've assumed your `.htaccess` file is in the document root - can you please confirm this? Do you have other `.htaccess` files in subdirectories? Please edit your question to include the complete `.htaccess` file with this directive in place.

Comment: I poorly explained so I will resume.
First, my htaccess is in the root and I don't have another .htaccess file.

I added the code at the start of the htaccess file as you requested:

Comment: If that directive/regex worked for one _subcategory_ then it should also work for two. (Unless your URLs with two subcategories include a trailing slash? But this is not present in the examples you've posted?) Make sure you are not seeing a cached response - clear your browser cache. Is it definitely not  triggering any redirect at all? Or is the redirect incorrect? Or is the redirect happening but you are still seeing a 404? What is the _exact_ URL you are requesting?

Comment: myproduct page:       
https://www.calotee.com/shop/crazy-cat-test-t-shirt/


- my old product page (404 error):
https://www.calotee.com/shop/women/t-shirt/crazy-cat-test-t-shirt/                                 


- test adress with one category (Works):                 
https://www.calotee.com/shop/category/crazy-cat-test-t-shirt/              

- you may put anything else "category" and it works.                 

- And it is not a cache problem. I tried it in private navigation mode and in other browsers.

Comment: Your actual URLs appear to contain a trailing slash, which is different to the "example" URLs you posted earlier (which do not include a trailing slash). I've updated my answer to allow for this trailing slash. As mentioned in my comment above, the initial directive I posted would not work if the URL contained a trailing slash, so it is a bit of a mystery how your old URLs with "one category" appeared to "work"?

Comment: It works fine. Thank You very Much @MrWhite